# maven resource filter xml

Tags: xml, maven, resources, filtering

I am trying to use respurce filtering for .properties & .xml files.
I am having a ${variable} value and maven replaces the ${--} with its real value.
I am able to achieve this for properties files, but for .xml file I am not sure how to do it.

My pom.xml

```
<resource>
<directory>${basedir}/../</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
<includes>
 <include>filename/*.properties</include>
</includes>
  </resource>
```

My properties file

value=${value}

I am kind of following this approach
http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/10/filtered-resources-in-maven/

Similar question was posted:

Comment: what about `<include>filename/*.xml</include>` ?

Comment: You configuration `${basedir}/../` looks weird. Usually resources are in `src/main/resources` or in `src/test/resources`...

Comment: I was able to make it work by <include>filename/*.xml</include> but had to modify my code a bit. Thanks @michaldo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like you could use the SoftSmithy Parent POM as your parent POM.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.softsmithy</groupId>
    <artifactId>softsmithy-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</parent>
```

The SoftSmithy Parent POM is a general purpose parent POM with many reasonable defaults.

E.g. it configures all files in src/main/resources and src/test/resources to be filtered and all files in src/main/resources-bin and src/test/resources-bin not to be filtered (intended for binary files such as images or text files you don't want to filter).

It might be a good starting point.

The SoftSmithy Parent POM is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-parent/blob/master/pom.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding an include tag:

filename/*.xml

Thanks everyone for your help